# JavaScript: absolute URL as es-module address in imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, browser, import

Is it possible to use absolute URLs for es6-modules `import` in browsers?

```js
import something from 'https://example.com/js/lib/es6_module.mjs';
```

As I know, it is impossible for nodejs. I have the following error in this case:

> Uncaught Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only file and data URLs are supported by the default ESM loader. Received protocol 'https:'

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. I've check it for browsers Chrome (94), Firefox (v93), Opera (v79).

This is HTML import:

```html
<script type="module">
    import fn from 'https://example.com/module.mjs';
    fn();
</script>
```

This is es-module import:

```js
import fn from 'https://exmaple.com/module.mjs';
fn();
```

Site `example.com` must have CORS enabled (apache config for example):

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use these

- https://github.com/egoist/import-http.git for webpack/rollup
- https://github.com/denoland/deno.git for js/ts runtime